# HDR image reading and writing in opencv

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I had written code for hdr image reading in opencv whenever i try to compile that i am getting ‘TonemapDurand’ was not declared in this scope
this type of error.

```
#include"opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include "vector"
#include "bits/stdc++.h"
#include "fstream"

using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char** argv )
{
    vector<Mat>images;
    Mat image;
    image = imread( argv[1], 1 );
    images.push_back(image);
    Mat ldr;
    Ptr<TonemapDurand> tonemap = createTonemapDurand(2.2f);
    tonemap->process(images[0], ldr);
    imwrite("ldr.png", ldr * 255);
    waitKey(0);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: which version of opencv are you using ? 3.1.0 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there is no HDR support in OpenCV 2.4.9, as you can see from [here](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.9/modules/photo/doc/photo.html).

You have to install OpenCV 3 for doing your experiments on HDR.

There is a nice blog on using HDR in OpenCV [here](https://www.learnopencv.com/high-dynamic-range-hdr-imaging-using-opencv-cpp-python/)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have missed some includes in your code :

```
#include <opencv2/photo.hpp>
```